# Count # of cells in between separate values in offsetting rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I'm trying to count how many orders a customer has in a month long period. I'm trying to add the invoice totals(Column H) for all occurrences between "Customer 1" and "Total for Customer 1". This formula has to be able to look up these values because their location changes each month.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm quite stuck.

I should note there are many more customers above in this spreadsheet also containing matching information for invoice and accounts receivable in respective columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATCH returns the matching row number. Subtract one from the other and adjust the difference to compensate for your layout.

```
=match("Total for Customer 1", a:a, 0)-match("Customer 1", a:a, 0)-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Ended up going with.

=ABS(MATCH("Customer 1",A:A,0)-MATCH("Total for Customer 1",A:A,0))-1

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution can only be sketchy.

I propose you use the method COUNTA(cellstart:cellend), which return the number of non blank cells in the range provided. You could do something like :
COUNTA(B106:B999999).

Yes, this is sketchy.